# Scale button without affect other buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, scale

I have a LinearLayout, i create(programatically) and adds buttons to it

```
public void initButtons(){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            new android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(dpiToPixels(context, 100), dpiToPixels(context,100)));
    params.setMargins(dpiToPixels(context,20), 0, 0, 0);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
}

 layout.addView(button, index);
```

When user touch(onTouchListener) any button i want to scale it:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button
                        .getLayoutParams();
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    lp.width = (int) (93 * Resources.getSystem()
                            .getDisplayMetrics().density);
                    lp.height = (int) (93 * Resources.getSystem()
                            .getDisplayMetrics().density);
                    button.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    lp.width = (int) (100 * Resources.getSystem()
                            .getDisplayMetrics().density);
                    lp.height = (int) (100 * Resources.getSystem()
                            .getDisplayMetrics().density);

                    button.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

The problem is that when i press one button down it affects every other buttons on the LinearLayout( looks scaled and moving a little left). Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It looks as though your layout is not able to distinguish between every button. Can you post more code where you are adding each button and applying listeners on them?

Comment: Update with how i init buttons

Comment: There is no id or tag for each button, how do you differentiate between them? If you add like 5 buttons, how do you know which button you pressed?

Comment: Actually buttons here is an attribute of my class. So i create 5 objects with instance of my class and get the buttons with: myClassObject.getButton()

Comment: When a button pressed others havent the same affect as the pressed one. Fewer scale and moving a little left

Comment: Try making your xml with assigning weights to each button. That way when a button is scaled, it should still retain its position in the layout and wont affect the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is bound to happen in a LinearLayout.

Try using FrameLayout. In a frameLayout, changing one button size won't affect others.

You can also use a RelativeLayout, but you shouldn't position your buttons 'relative' to others in it.

Comment: I want to keep the linearLayout, when i add a button it aligns automatically one next to other (i need this)